# How to display long script logs to one liner?

Tags: bash, shell

Lets Say I have multiple scripts which need to invoke sequentially for the job.
These scripts has long and lengthy output this is my bash script,
How to avoid that but still can understand that the process is running.
Here is an example,

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Script to prepare Final BUILD"
rm -vf module1.out
module1_build_script.sh #FIXME: This scripts outputs 10000 lines
#module1_build_script.sh &> /dev/null #Not interested as this makes difficult if the process hangs or running.
if [ ! -f ./out/module1.out ];then
    echo "Module 1 build failed" 
    exit 1
fi
. 
.
.

rm -vf module1.out
module4_build_script.sh # This scripts outputs 5000 lines
if [ ! -f ./out/module4.out ];then
    echo "Module 4 build failed" 
    exit 4
fi
```

Now I am expecting some code gives me effect like below output as one liner without scroll
example:  **module1_build_script.sh | "magical code here"** #FIXME:

Like below output

```
user@bash#./myscript
#-------content of myscript ---------------
#!/bin/bash
while (( i < 10))
do
    echo -en "\r Process is running...$i"
    sleep 0.5
    ((i++))

done
#------------------------------------------
```

Comment: you can delete line break `tr -d '\n'`

Comment: @Dipankar : Why don't you just redirect the output of the script to a file?

Comment: @DigvijayS that actually not the ask, is there a way to replace those  "\n" to "\r" which might address the issue.

Comment: `tr '\n' '\r' `

Comment: @user1934428 that's acceptable but is there a way to show in current screen that the process is running, may be by progress bar or something. NOTE: we have no control on the long output scripts.

Comment: You can `tail -f` the file .... though I don't know whether this is good enough for a progress bar.